# I have a scenario when i need to insert into table from same table after changing some column. Issue is key Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

let say,

```
insert into A  select * from A where col1 = "ABC"
```

leads to an error as there would be the same primary key column, I want to increment automatically from the max id the table have

```
CREATE TABLE  A(
    [WFID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [EntityID1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntityID2] [int] NULL);



INSERT INTO WFCustom
SELECT * FROM WFCustom
WHERE EntityID2 = 6008 ,
```

getting an error as WFID is a primary key :

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_WF_Custom'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.WFCustom'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Specify a column list on both the `INSERT` and `SELECT` without the `IDENTITY` column. The incremental value will be assigned automatically.

Comment: i missed by saying identity column, my meaning was it should have a unique not null value, removing the name from select will result in error

Comment: `IDENTITY` columns will be assigned a unique not null value when you omit the `IDENTITY` column from the `INSERT` columns list. Try it.

Comment: @Dan Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'WFID', table '**.dbo.WFCustom'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You said you had an `IDENTITY` column but the DDL shows you do not.

Comment: sorry for that, i don't have identity col. Will update questioin

Comment: You will suffer from performance and concurrency problems (i.e. using `MAX`) unless you use and `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`. I suggest you use one of those approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
INSERT INTO wfcustom 
SELECT (SELECT Max(wfid) 
        FROM   WFCustom) + (Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) AS id, 
       entityid1, 
       entityid2 
FROM   wfcustom
```

**[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/DTKZ68249)**

**Note:**

As suggested by **@DanGuzman**, insert can fail in scenarios when same query is running from multiple sessions under  `read committed isolation level`. So it's always advisable to use `Identity` column for this type of scenarios.

Comment: If this query is run from 2 sessions at the same time in the read committed isolation level, duplicate values may result.

Comment: @DanGuzman, i have updated the answer accordingly, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to fix your data model.  This would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    [WFID] int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [EntityID1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntityID2] [int] NULL
);

INSERT INTO WFCustom (EntityID1, EntityID2)
    SELECT EntityID1, EntityID2
    FROM WFCustom
    WHERE EntityID2 = 6008;
```

This is the safest method for being sure that primary keys are unique -- the database takes care of it.

If that doesn't work, you can assign a new one.  The method proposed by PSK is fine, although I would write it as:

```
INSERT INTO WFCustom (WFID, EntityID1, EntityID2)
    SELECT (COALESCE(MAX_WFID, 0) +
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WFID)
           ) as new_WFID,
           EntityID1, EntityID2
    FROM WFCustom CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(WFID) as MAX_WFID FROM WFCustom) m
    WHERE EntityID2 = 6008;
```